# How to trigger a tooltip during an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, tooltip

I am building a WPF application which consists of 9 textboxes which can only accept integer values. When any other symbol other than integer is encountered, it will throw an exception.
I want a tooltip to be triggered with a message whenever an exception is thrown, how can I do that using only C#? Here is my code-

```
 private void a1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NumOnly(sender, e);
        try
        {
            eq1[0] = int.Parse(a1.Text);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            tp.Opacity = 0.7;
            tp.Content = "Only Integers allowed!";
            tp.StaysOpen = true;
            a1.ToolTip=tp;
        }
    }
```

the problem is that the tooltip is only visble when the mouse hovers the textbox, how can I make the tooltip visible without hovering the mouse?

Comment: Tooltips are not typically used to report such data input errors to the user. The tooltip should say that integers are required when the user hovers over the textbox, but it would go against years of convention to use a tooltip to report the error. Others may disagree with me, but that's why I voted the question down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well..

using tooltip for excaption handling is a bad practice and you shouldn't do it.

have a textblock near the textbox with error msg in red.

like in login forms in websites.

see:

[c#: is there a way to force a tooltip to show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143428/c-is-there-a-way-to-force-a-tooltip-to-show)

if you insist:

[How do I force showing a tooltip in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657099/how-do-i-force-showing-a-tooltip-in-wpf)

answeres your question

Comment: @Sidsec9 hi SId and welcome to stack overflow when someone gives you a good a nswer in stack overflow it is customery. to "+1" this answer. and mark it it as the selected answer. to reward them for their efforts.

Comment: I never knew! I', sorry! Marking +1 to all the answers that haveve helped so far.